# Definition of a reducing subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, intuition, unbounded-operators

Gerald Teschl in his book "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" defines a *reducing subspace* of an unbounded operator the following way:

> Let $T$ be an unbounded operator on a complex Hilbert $H$ space with domain $D(T)\subseteq H$. A closed subspace $A\subseteq H$ is said to be a *reducing subspace of $T$* if $P_AT\subseteq TP_A$, where $P_A$ is the orthogonal projection onto $A$.

I can't really get behind this definition. What does this intuitively mean? Is there a relation to invariant subspaces?

Comment: As a start, you might like to figure out what the domains of $P_A T$ and $T P_A$ are, and what it says for one to be contained in the other.